# php odbc_connect to mssql works in linux/ubuntu command line not browser

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, odbc, freetds

I really feel like I have done an exhaustive search on this matter, found similar issues and have tried a number of things without success, so I am for the first time posting a question here:

I do a lot of web pages/web programming (PHP/jQuery mostly) and host these pages on my digital library department's Drupal/Ubuntu Server. I just code them and post them via Dreamweaver, as I don't have much use for the Drupal front end. I just need the server for my pages.

Anyway, I am wanting to make some PHP pages that can connect to our library catalog, so I have been working from the command line of the Drupal/Ubuntu server. I installed unixODBC, had some troubles, installed FreeTDS, set up the drivers and the DSN.

Finally...

1. I was able to get a connection to our catalog via tsql and run a query.
2. I made a basic PHP script to test the connection:

   - It works from the Ubuntu command line of the server (connection successful).
   - It doesn't work when I load it in a browser. I get the dreaded:

> Warning: odbc_pconnect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in /var/www/mydirectory/mytestpage.php on line 15

**UPDATE:** I installed a test Ubuntu Server in a partition on my laptop, where I started clean, installed Apache2/PHP5(with mssql and odbc modules, etc)/FreeTDS, etc. I got a tsql connection. I made the basic PHP script and ran it successfully from the command line. Then I navigated to the php page from a browser and *it worked!* I still need to get this to happen on the Drupal server version, but now I have at least narrowed down the issue to something on the Drupal server.

I searched and found such possible causes as:

1. File permissions, which I think I got corrected, but no go
2. That maybe I had set up a User DNS and not a System DNS which I tried my best to correct with the proper "odbcinst" command options
3. That maybe php needs to be running in CGI mode instead of as a module. But that seemed unlikely from what I read. And I am not sure how that would affect Drupal. (There are limits to the system wide changes I should make here.)
4. A number of people said it was SElinux blocking Apache from displaying the page in the browser, but temporarily disabling SElinux didn't work.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Check you have enabled the mssql.so etc at the following location

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, you will be having another at /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

in ubuntu php.ini will be maintained separately for cli & mod_php apache configuration

Comment: Oh man, I was really hoping that was it. But both of those places have mssql.so enabled. Thanks so much anyway, though, as you just taught me something I didn't know! Thanks again!

Comment: Are all the settings for mssql within the actual mssql section of the INI file the same? I believe there is a block of various settings for different connectors.

Comment: I am actually just settling in to compare the two INI files and see what's different. I think you must be on to something with the difference between the two files, as it makes so much sense in the context of what's happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to test your odbc sources on the commandline, I would advise you use the isql utility instead of tsql. isql uses the DSN you defined in odbc.ini to connect to the database, while tsql connects directly to your database.

If it works with isql, it should work on your webpage as well.

Also check the Drupal/Ubuntu Server files /etc/odbc.ini (your DSN sources) and /etc/odbcinst.ini (TDS Driver settings) to see if they match the ones on the working Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it has something to do with the php. ini file. On my Ubuntu system I've got 2.
One in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
And one in /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
 The values in the apache2 path will need to be adjusted to allow the connection. Unfortunately outside of that I'm not too much use as I use MySQL and Mongo

Comment: Hmm. You're the second person to mention those separate php.ini files. I made sure that both enable the mssql extension, but maybe I should just do a full on comparison of the apache2 and cli php.ini files to see if something is different... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `php.ini` from work server to non-work server, add make needed environment variables accessible before starting your web server, and make sure your web-server has full  access to your `odbc` and `odbcinst ini-files`. And so, using mssql knowledge base or help.